# Activiti compensation

Tags: activiti, bpmn

***What I want***

I look for way to roll back Activiti context before it reach a wait state. For example, I have:

```
public class MyService implements JavaDelegate {

  @Override
  public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) {
    int a = calcA();
    boolean res1 = saveToDB(a);  // save to application context
    execution.setVariable("a" , a); //save to activiti context

    if (!a)
      rollback(); //rollback execution contaxt 
  }
}
```

***What a problem:***

I don't want manually remove execution variables. I've alredy tried common transaction - no result. Now I think about compensation events.

***Question:***

*Does compensation event rollback Activiti context or I should do it manually in an appropriate CompensationserviceTask?*

Comment: Nice representation of question!

Comment: If you throw an exception in your Delegate Activiti will rollback and retry the whole transaction. Is this what you want? Have a look at http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#bpmnConcurrencyAndTransactions to learn about transaction borders.

Comment: I've read it. Also I've read about common transaction for Activiti and Hibernate. Seems the last is a myth, because I didn't find any example in Google and I wast about two weeks and no result. But the point is that Activiti DOESN'T ROLLBACK it context after I throw an exception. May you provide me a reference to working example (desirable with postgres and spring, but all are welcome)

Comment: You need to use the following properties for your engine config in addition to the other properties.
`<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">      
 <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
 <property name="jpaEntityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
 <property name="jpaHandleTransaction" value="true" />
 <property name="jpaCloseEntityManager" value="true" />
</bean>`

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an exception will do the trick, it will rollback the entire transaction from the engine.